How were the Oracles of Zeus, Apollo, and Mars different?
Consider these oracles:

Delphi: All but ubiquitous,
Apollo was said to speak through the Pythia
Dodona: Here it was Zeus, not Apollo; Zeus Ammon in Siwa also comes to mind
Tiora
Matien: An
oracle of Mars, though attestations are much sparser compared to the
first two; its exact function seems to have little attention by
scholars

The only differences I've encountered are limited to either trivial things like fame, or mechanical differences, such as how the oracle was staffed. For instance, Strabo flags that the oracles of Dodona were initially carried out by men (similar to my post here, on the Oracle of Didyma, which also experienced a period of male oracles:Why were male oracles replaced by female oracles? ):

At the outset, it is true, those who uttered the prophecies were men
(this too perhaps the poet indicates, for he calls them “hypophetae”
[interpreters] and the prophets might be ranked among these), but
later on three old women were designated as prophets, after Dione also
had been designated as temple-associate of Zeus. (Strabo, Geography
7.7)

There is also, of course, the renown of the oracle that varied. (i.e. Delphi was the most famous).
I was thinking perhaps it was the nature of the oracle by the questioner that might matter, for instance war-related queries might be better suited to the Oracle of Mars. However, the Delphic had plenty to say about the Persian Wars, so that defeats my thesis so far. But I haven't exhaustively considered all the variables at play, I think we may still learn something by comparing some of the oracles based on the deity (Zeus or Apollo or Mars-Ares)
Question
Beyond the differences in how old each were or if staffed by men or women, do we have epigraphical evidence that shows any differences in the nature of the oracular function itself, based on who the deity at the site was (Apollo vs Zeus vs Mars-Ares)? In other words, were there qualitative distinctions recorded based on the deity? (possibly: differences in terms of scope of eligible questions or perhaps efficacy or patronage)
I guess regional mythographic accounts will shape the solution set of which deities are selected for a city's oracle, but that doesn't seem to inform us if the "end product" of the oracles differed qualitatively based on the deity: whether they did indeed differ or if it was a difference without a distinction.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Not sufficient by itself to answer, but a data point to consider: the oracle at Delphi is older than the temple of Apollo there and was originally associated with Gaia.
